# R Scraping html webpage using XML

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping, rstudio, rcurl

I am trying to scrape this webpage using the following code.

```
library(XML)
url <- html("http://www.gallop.co.za/")
doc <- htmlParse(url)
lat <- xpathSApply(doc,path="//p[@id=Racecards]",fun = xmlGetAttr , name = 'Racecards')
```

I looked at the webpage and the table i want to scrape is the racecard table, primarily to get the links to where the racecard data is.

I used selector gadget which returns the xml path as:

```
//*[(@id = "Racecards")]
```

However, when i use the R code, it returns a zero list. It feels like i'm getting the xml path wrong somehow, what is the correct way to return the table but also return the links within the table?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the data are transported through `json` and use `js` to insert into html. So you can't get the data from `html`. You can get it directly from `json`.

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

p <- getURL("http://www.gallop.co.za/cache/horses.json")
fromJSON(p)
```

Comment: That's incredible. How did you figure out that the location was http://www.gallop.co.za/cache/horses.json?

Comment: You can use firebug in firefox browser or F12 in chrome, to inspect network transfer. Then according to it, figure out where data stored.